# phonegap unable to integrate with facebook

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to perform Facebook login on my Phonegap application dedicated especially for Windows Phone platform.

I've downloaded required plugin (files: ChildBrowserCommand.cs, ChildBrowser.js) and FBConnect.js available at https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone. I've also included ChildBrowser.cs file into my project

Below is my simple html file. After some time i want to perform Facebook login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/run/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/ChildBrowser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/FBConnect.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $.support.cors = true;
    </script>
    <div id="testPage" data-role="page">
         <script>
             setTimeout(function () {
                 var client_id = "...";
                 var redir_url = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
                 var friendsMap = {};

                 var fb = FBConnect.install(client_id, redir_url, "touch");
                 fb.connect('email, read_stream, read_friendlists');
                 fb.onConnect = onFBConnected;
             }, 2500);

             function onFBConnected() {
             }
            </script>
        <div data-role="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I compile my project I got following errors:

```
1. The type or namespace name 'BaseCommand' could not be found
2. The type or namespace name 'JSON' does not exist in the namespace 'WP7CordovaClassLib.Cordova'
```

About first error, I saw that there are incorrect namespaces in ChildBrowserCommand.cs file. I've fix this issue, but I don't know where to find missing JSON module. After download Phonegap 2.9.1 from archive there is possibility to create Visual Studio templates (under lib/windows-phone directory after unzipping and I've done it), but it seems that library might not be complete. There's still one error remaining and I can't perform my Facebook login. Have you ever encountered that problem? Where to find this missing module? Below is my ChildBrowserCommand.cs changes. I would appreciate any help!

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using WP7CordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands; // previous: using WP7CordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WP7CordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON; // it's missing
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Some time ago I've found very good solution available [HERE](https://github.com/studiosoton/faceGap). And it works for my Windows Phone application! In order to perform Facebook login properly you need to setup InAppBrowser plugin in your Phonegap project and enter your App ID and App Secret keys before *.FaceGap* method call. Brilliant! :)